# MaTeX documentation not available in documentation center

Tags: documentation, matex

Typing "MaTeX" in the documentation center doesn't give any hits. Do I have to do anything before this works?

I tried uninstalling and re-installing MaTeX (via `PacletInstall`, version is now 1.7.3), no success and I couldn't find similar issues on the web.

Edit: Solved.

Comment: What version of Mathematica?

Comment: Sorry, it's 11.1.1.0

Comment: Hmm, I just quickly installed it from the website with `PacletInstall[MaTeX-1.7.3.paclet]` and in both 11.1 and 11.2 when I search the documentation for MaTeX I get taken to the main doc page. Not sure why yours would be different. Note my tests were on Windows.

Comment: Thanks for the effort!
I'm on mac OS 10.13.2. Maybe anybody else?

Comment: *MaTeX* is not a part of the Wolfram software, nor explicitly supported by Wolfram Research... it is an add-on.  I do hope Wolfram will incorporate this system, or write their own, to make their typesetting and display as nice as $\LaTeX$.

Comment: Please join the MaTeX chatroom and we will figure out what is wrong on your system. https://gitter.im/MaTeX-help/Lobby

Comment: Alright, restarting mathematica just miraculously solved the issue. Thanks for the fast replies!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem fixed itself and cannot be reproduced.

Comment: That's fine. The hint for a possibly required restart after installation might be included in the documentation by Szabolcs.

Comment: You need to use @, as in @Szabolcs, to be sure he is notified of your comment and sees your suggestion. -- I have to say that resetting and restarting have been standard trouble-shooting advice probably since electronic machines were invented. :)

Comment: I've been talking to him. And just didn't expect a restart to have an effect, but I agree - this one's one me ;)